# Ruby grammar problem . I don't know how to solve it

Tags: ruby

```
Please output the number obtained by adding a and b.

At the end of the line break, do not include extra characters, blank lines.

expmple1
1 1

result1
2

expmple2
0 99

result2
99
```

My code is:

```
input_lines = gets.chop
a = input_lines[0]
b = input_lines[1]

puts a + b
```

But it's not working, please help.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You say that "you solve the problem", so why are you asking this question if the problem is solved?

Comment: Also, so you say that you have a problem with Ruby's grammar, but I don't see any syntactical problems in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `split` to the chopped gets would work:

```
input_lines = gets.chop.split
a = input_lines[0].to_i
b = input_lines[1].to_i

puts a + b
```

Try it.
Check [String doc.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html)

More DRY way to do it:

```
input_lines = gets.chop.split.map(&:to_i)
a,b = input_lines

puts a + b
```

In this case the numbers inside `input_lines` already changed to Integers.

Comment: `to_i` is needed

Comment: @Santhosh  Updated. Thanks :)